# php script not working via crontab on mac

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

I want to automate an mysql db backup task with this script:

https://github.com/axllent/phpmybackup

Therefor I created an run.sh shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash   
php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/db-backup/run.php
```

In run.php I have this code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require('phpmybackup.php');
$db = new MYSQL_DUMP;
$db->dbhost = 'myhost';
$db->dbuser = 'myuser';
$db->dbpwd = 'mypw';

$db->backupsToKeep = 30;
$db->showDebug = true;
$db->includeDatabases = ['*'];
//phpinfo();
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($db->dumpDatabases());
?>
```

So when I run the run.sh script in the console the script works fine!

But If I let the crontab do the job I get an error in the log:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Operation timed out in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/db-backup/phpmybackup.php on line 77
Cannot connect to myhost (Operation timed out
```

I know that my host needs an approval of ip's which are allowed to access, but this is set and if the script works in the terminal, why doesn't it in the crontab?

Here is the crontab command:

```
* 12 * * *  cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/db-backup && ./run.sh >/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/log/cron.log
```

Comment: Looks like the connection to the database timed out, maybe double-check the db host, user, password and port. Can you connect to that server from that machine using mysql cli?

Comment: Is it working when you execute it manually like `cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/db-backup && ./run.sh >/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/log/cron.log` ?

Comment: @ChrisG Yup, this command works!

Comment: @JulienB. host, user and pw are correct, since the run.php script works e.g. from the browser.

Comment: Is this crontab for your user? Is the server up when running the crontab?

Comment: Very strange situation. What exactly is in `phpmybackup.php on line 77` .. maybe this helps us more..

Comment: Another possibility is .. let me give you an example: `GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';` ... so user jeffry is able to access from 'localhost', but 'localhost' and 127.0.0.1 is not always the same (in opinion of mysql.. ) i had such a problem some weeks ago.

Comment: @JulienB. Which user do you mean? Mac or mysql? Server is up. Again, which do you mean? The local server for php or the online web-server where the mysql db is running?

Comment: @ChrisG not really interesting, just the db connection: $this->con = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpwd);

Comment: I was asking about the user for which the crontab is created so Mac user. Oh, the mysql db is not running locally? If so 'user'@'localhost' is not going to work.

Comment: did you check the user rights? .. regarding the Host? Change the User Host to % and give a try.

Comment: weirdly enough, without changing anything. now the script seems to works...